# Trying to read external file in flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am developing mobile application where I have external document (TXT file) to read the strings from, but I keep having this error saying that no such directory as shown below

```
E/flutter ( 8649): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.tafseer_mp3/app_flutter/suwaru.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
E/flutter ( 8649): #0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9)
E/flutter ( 8649): #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
E/flutter ( 8649): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter ( 8649): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8649):
```

Below is my file utility codes

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

class FileUtility{
  //get phone path directory
  static Future<String> get getPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }
  //get file location
  static Future<File> get getFile async {
    final path = await getPath;
    return File('$path/suwaru.txt');
  }
 

  static Future<String> readFile() async {
    try {
      final file = await getFile;
      final content = file.readAsString();
      return content;
    } catch (e) {
      return '';
    }
  }


}
```

Please help me out, Thanks

Comment: Is a write being called before the first read?

Comment: Have you verified that the file exists at that exact path, and if so, how did you verify it?

Answer (score 0):

Read the file from assets folder

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
getData() async {
      String data;
      data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/suwaru.txt');
      setState((){
        suwaru = data;
      });
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).